# How Can we implement HeaderCheckBox to Checked && UnChecked based on the Items selected in Telerik Gridview?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radgrid

I am Having a Telerik Gridview in which items were displayed along with checkbox for each row.
I am having One HeaderCheckbox , if we select HeaderCheckbox to selected then all the Checkboxes were checked without any issues.
Now If i Uncheck any one Item, then the HeaderCheckbox has to be uncheked and how can i implement this using javascript or telerik gridview ?

Comment: Its Radgrid's inbuilt functionality no need to write javascript for this check this http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/selecting/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Are you using the built in `ClientSelectColumn`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. is there any way to do same in javascript way ?

Comment: do you know how to do this with normal gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you've implemented this, but the `RadGrid` has a `GridClientSelectColumn` that should handle all of that for you.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowMultiRowSelection="true" ...>
    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="SelectRow">
                <HeaderStyle Width="27px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>          
            ...       
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true" EnableAlternatingItems="true">                                                                                    
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
    </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```